# get all <option> value in drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get all option values of dropdown? And can i hide them, by they value?
For example i have dropdown list with 12 monthes, now is 11 october 2012, and i'd like to hide all monthes from past, and show only 3 - October, November, December.

Here is how i try to da that, can u tell me, how can i get the option value in that loop, because `this.val()` do not return it?

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
if (year == $('#yearSelected', '#BookingCalendar').val()){
  $('#monthSelected option', '#BookingCalendar').each(
    function (){
      if(this.val() < month) this.hide();
    }
  );     
}
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code as well.

Comment: Either `this.value` or `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following line:

```
if (this.value < month)   // 'this' is DOM object
    $(this).hide();       // '$(this)' is jQuery object
```